# determine the value of k for which the function is a joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

the function is:
$f(x,y)= kx^2y$, $x=1,2,\; y=1,2,3$

I don’t understand how to do this because it doesn’t say the limits for the integral to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

No integral or [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) is involved here.

You must find the $k$ that satisfies $\sum_{x=1}^2\sum_{y=1}^3kx^2y=1$.

For that $k$ function $f$ is a [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function).